# What is the use of () in javascript for initializing variables?

Tags: javascript

I know that `var some = [];` creates a new array and `var someother = {}` creates a new object. So what does the `()` do?

Specifically, in the following code :

```
var someVar = (1,2,3); //someVar equals 3
```

and

```
typeof (1,2,3) //returns "number"
```

So what does the `()` do in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [precedences of operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

```
(1,2,3)
```

is just

```
3
```

because the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) returns the last value.

The parenthesis in

```
typeof (1,2,3)
```

just prevent it to be interpreted as

```
(typeof 1),2,3
```

because the typeof operator has a higher precedence than the comma operator.

Answer (score 0):

That is [a grouping operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.6).

It causes the contents to be evaluated as an expression in their own right. Effectively it changes precedence since otherwise the `someVar = 1` would be evaluated first (instead of the result of `(1,2,3)` being evaluated and the result used in the `someVar = ...` expression.

That expression `1,2,3` uses [a comma operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14) which evaluates as *the right hand side*, so it is `3`.